# Django calculate distinct sum of many to many field in line items

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am trying to create an invoice system. An invoice can have multiple line items and each line item can have multiple taxes - some items can have 3 taxes, while some have only 2, while some are tax-free.

I want to calculate the total taxes on the invoice model, but I also want to represent the total sum of different taxes.

For example: Item 1 is $100 (with 15% VAT) and Item 2 is $100 (with 15% VAT and 10% CAT). I want to show the total taxes for the invoice - VAT: $30 ; CAT: $10)

I have three models.

This is invoice model

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    sub_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits...)
    taxes = models.DecimalField(...)
    final_total = models.DecimalField(...)

def calc_sub_total(self):
    sub_total = 0
    for each in self.invoiceitems.all():
        sub_total = sub_total + each.total
    return sub_total

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.sub_total = self.calc_sub_total
    self.final_total = self.calc_sub_total - self.discount + self.charges
```

This is invoice items model

```
class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, related_name="invoiceitems")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits...)
    price = models.DecimalField(...)
    taxes = models.ManyToManyField(Tax, related_name="taxitems")
    final_total = models.DecimalField(...)

def calc_item_total(self):
    total = self.price * self.quantity
    return total

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.total = self.calc_item_total()
    super(InvoiceItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    i = Invoice.objects.get(id=self.invoice_id)
    i.save()
```

This is the tax model

```
class Tax(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    rate = models.DecimalField(..)
```

Comment: What is your question? What problem do you need help solving? [ask]

Comment: I want to calculate the total taxes on the invoice model, but I also want to represent the total sum of different taxes. English isn't my first language I'm trying my best.

Comment: What problem are you facing when trying to do that? You can create a method called `calculate_taxes` on your `Invoice` class to summarize taxes.

Comment: I agree with @HåkenLid, and also you may use Inline Formsets (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) in order to get multiple foreign key objects of an invoice

Comment: Thanks, I am using admin inline form. I am able to calculate everything but taxes, trying to figure out the queryset.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the sum of all the taxes like this:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):

    ...

    def calculate_taxes(self):
        taxes = 0
        for item in self.invoiceitems.all():
            price = item.price * item.quantity
            taxes += sum(tax.rate for tax in item.taxes.all())
        return taxes
```

This just returns a number, if you need to know the type of tax etc, modify the method.